# Masonry style with css2 for better browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

Is there any way to do the masonry grid in css2 for a better browser compatibility ?

I know the way to do it with css3 attribute but I care about old browser.
And masonry js plugin is too low to append the formatted grid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible using

### css2 + jQuery

See demo Here - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/QdGgc/)

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h2"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h2"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h2"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h2"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h2"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h1"></div>
    <div class="item w1 h2"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
    #container {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #4D4;
}
.w1 {
    width: 70px;
}
.h1 {
    height: 70px;
}
.w2 {
    width: 150px;
}
.h2 {
    height: 150px;
}
```

---

### css3

And using **pure css3** demo - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Chkz/)

---

### cool jQuery Plugins

- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
- [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

[both works in **IE8+** and **modern browsers**, including mobile browsers on **iOS** and **Android**]